# grid.getCellValue string in numpy array fails

Tags: numpy, wxpython

I have a numpy array with several strings e.g. `'4:30:30'` or `'3:29:11'`

I write these values in a `wxpython` grid.

The other way arround doesn not work, why?

```
arr[0] = self.grid.GetCellValue(0,0)
```

error message:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 4:2:21
```

Some experiments with the array `(dtype = None)` did not help...

Anyone an idea?

Comment: self.grid.GetCellValue(0,0).split(":")